# How to safely pass parameters to ActiveRecord#select() when using PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a method that takes a column name and defines a scope on my model. The scope makes use of PostgreSQL window functions (like rank() and row_number()), adding an additional column to the resulting dataset. For example, `User.ranked_on_score` should add a `rank()` column aliased as `score_ranking`.

Currently, I achieved it with simple string interpolation (pseudocode):

```
window_alias = "#{attr}_rankings"
result_alias = "#{attr}_ranking"

select("users.*, #{window_alias}.#{result_alias}")
.join("JOIN (SELECT id, rank() OVER (ORDER BY #{attr} ASC) as #{result_alias} ...")
```

Considering, the scope should be defined be a macro beforehand and doesn't take input from users, this approach should be safe; nevertheless, I don't like it.

I know about the `sanitize_sql` method, but it doesn't work in my case. It wraps parameters in single quotes which is fine in the `WHERE` clause, but raises syntax errors if used in the `SELECT` clause (PG requires identifiers to be wrapped in double quotes).

Is there any built-in method for identifier sanitization? Or should I just leave it like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [`quote_column_name`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/quoting.rb#L153)?  It's undocumented for some reason, but should do what you need.

```
window_alias = quote_column_name("#{attr}_rankings")
result_alias = quote_column_name("#{attr}_ranking")
```

Under the hood, it's equivalent to calling [`PGconn.quote_ident`](http://rubydoc.info/github/ged/ruby-pg/PGconn.quote_ident) when using PostgreSQL.